# Dialogflow: Print JSON response from webhook to user

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

I want to print the fulfilment response that I am getting from the webhook back to the user.

Using an open API for Cryptocompare as the webhook, i am receiving the JSON response i need, however I do not know how to print the response for the user (also translate from JSON to text)

Fulfilment Response:

```
{
  "BTC": 0.03181,
  "USD": 199.25,
  "EUR": 171.74
}
```

Fulfillment Status:
Webhook execution successful

I'm assuming i need to some how echo/print it under the custom payload tab.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert the JSON response to string in order to print it out. `JSON.stringify()` could the the job, put your return data inside the bracket.